# Use of Subquery on django's update

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-3.1

I'm currently getting this error

> Joined field references are not permitted in this query

Any idea why it happens if I do this? (models recreated into a simpler version)

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(
       Bar, related_name='foos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    baz = models.ForeignKey(
       Baz, related_name='foos', null=True, blank=True,
       on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Baz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I wanted to update the `baz` field of all `Foo` instances based on all `Baz` with the same name of `Foo`'s `bar`

```
Foo.objects.update(
    baz=Subquery(
        Baz.objects.filter(
            name=OuterRef('bar__name')
        ).values('pk')[:1]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by accessing it through `Bar`'s model and chaining `OuterRef`

```
Foo.objects.update(
    baz=Subquery(
        Baz.objects.filter(
            name=Subquery(
                Bar.objects.filter(
                    pk=OuterRef(OuterRef('bar_id'))
                ).values('name')[:1]
            )
        ).values('pk')[:1]
    )
)
```